# TCP: Client sends [RST, ACK] immediately after sending [ACK] to Server

Tags: wcf, nginx, tcp

I've got nginx 1.9.7 compiled against OpenSSL 1.0.2e running on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (3.13.0-71-generic x86_64). I can connect to it with a browser no problem at all, and get a secure connection.

I also have a client who is running some Windows Server and is trying to connect to using WCF. They report they aren't able to connect to my service.

My nginx error log shows:

```
2015/12/09 17:38:27 [info] 10750#0: *6494 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking, client: {REDACTED}, server: 0.0.0.0:443
```

Digging deeper, a Wireshark dump shows this pattern:

```
Client -> Server [SYN]
Client <- Server [SYN, ACK]
Client -> Server [ACK]
Client -> Server [RST, ACK]  (connection closes)
```

Sniffing a successful request shows:

```
Client -> Server [SYN]
Client <- Server [SYN, ACK]
Client -> Server [ACK]
Client -> Server [PSH, ACK] (sends SSL Client Hello)
```

I'm not really a TCP guy, so I'm a little out of my depth in understanding what could be happening here. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was the client's firewall :(

Edited to add detail: the client's firewall had been configured to block the domain and was therefore dropping the TCP connection as soon as it was established. Once the block was cleared, the issue went away.